# Closing Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Long ago I had a macro that would open some workbooks, do some fiddling, then close - all fully automated, called from the commandline so I could batch file it and stick it in windows schedule to run when needed.

I've had call to do it again and of course no longer have access to those files (like four companies ago) so had a bash at recreating them, but stuck on closing excel.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

This works to close the workbooks I'm updating, however, if I use it on the macro containing workbook, it closes the workbook within Excel, but leaves the instance of excel running (with no workbooks).

```
Application.Quit
```

This is what I think should be the right command, however this also throws an error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

However, it's odd. If I just run that command within excel on its own, there's no error, it only errors if the workbook calls the macro containing it.

As it's an auto-launching macro, I have an initial macro in `ThisWorkbook` that has the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` which kicks everything off.

I'd read that `Application.Quit` can cause this error message when the workbook has an auto-launching macro and it's called from a module, rather than ThisWorkbook, so I moved the `Sub QuitExcel()` that I created, containing just `Application.Quit` but still get this error.

The suggested posts from SO when posting this gave a few things to try, like `DisplayAlerts=False` and saving the workbook, so I updated my quit sub to:

```
Sub QuitExcel()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

(and various permutations of that)

However I still persist in getting the same error.

Interestingly, if I click "debug" (rather than end, continue is greyed out) Excel still quits, and doesn't actually go to debugging.

Anyone have experience in what I'm trying to achieve, I just want to kill Excel after it's finished running, from auto-launching a macro?

Comment: I am not sure I am able to get you... `Application.Quit` should quit Excel session. But it must be the last line in the code. How to save a workbook, or do anything else, after Excel session has been quitted? Now, if you open excel using automation, you should use the Excel application object instead of `Application`. I mean, using `Dim ExApp` followed by `Set ExApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` and open workbooks, or doing something else, you should use `ExApp.Quit`...

Comment: Usually, these two lines do the job: `ThisWorkbook.Save` and `Application.Quit`. For more information (if it doesn't work in your case), you should post the complete relevant code and share the details of where it is located (workbook, module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be relatively easy, I need to close my workbook before quitting excel and the closing macro can't be in the ThisWorkbook, it has to be in a module (otherwise when the workbook is closed, access to the rest of the code is gone).

So my command ended up being:

```
Sub QuitExcel()
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Just needed a bit more googling and trial/error.

Answer (score -2):

You should know that VBA code only run in a workbook context `ThisWorkBook` , that mean when you close it using `WorkBook.Close`, there will be no code to execute.
So, you only save then use `Application.Quit`
Do not close the workbook
`For Each w In Application.Workbooks  w.Save  Next w  Application.Quit`